# Center ProgressBar inside RecyclerView that is inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ProgressBar` that is an item of the `RecyclerView` and was added there with the adapter following this tutorial [Android RecyclerView dynamically load more items when scroll to end with bottom ProgressBar](http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/02/android-recyclerview-dynamically-load.html).

But instead of using a `RelativeLayout` in the `activity_main.xml` file, I'm using the default `ConstraintLayout`. The problem for me is that the `ProgressBar` isn't centered.

Please find below the layouts I've described above:

**The progress bar item**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.bookquotes.quotes.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is a screenshot of the `ProgressBar` that appears on the left (I need it to be centered):

[image: Non-centered progress bar]

Comment: I took another look at your issue and don't think my answer really addressed it. What does your screen look like when you say the progress bar is not centered? Can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a closer look at your issue and it is not clear at all what is going on. I have taken the sample project and applied your changes to the layouts and it works just fine. (I did remove a `tools` reference and changed a couple of ids.)

Here is the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/EndlessRecyclerView-ConstraintLayout) with the changes just to the two layouts above. Here is a [video of this modified app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7g7n.gif) that shows the progress bar in the center as expected.

I was thinking that this was a constraint issue but, as you can see from the demo, that is not the case.

It is also possible that this may be related to the version of `ConstraintLayout` you are running or some other configuration thing, so you may want to check that out. Otherwise, it looks like something else is going on that has not been revealed. Are you doing any other manipulation of the layout widgets?

It would be useful to know what in your layout is not lining up. Give the `LinearLayout` a background color to see if it stretching across the screen or not. That will tell you if the progress bar is misaligned  or whether the `LinearLayout` is pinched.

---

One other possibility: Are you failing to name the parent in the inflation of the `LinearLayout`? Say something like this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, null, false);
```

instead of this

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
```

That small difference will shove your progress bar to the side.

Comment: The missing `parent` in the `inflater` was the main cause of the `ProgressBar` being not centered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add gravity to your parent LinearLayout which sets the child's gravity to center.I have corrected the progressbar layout.
Hope this could help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center in middle of screen ?
Or just inside the linear layout 
Try gravity instead of layout gravity which will try to center inside the linear layout instead of constraint layout. Since you already have match parent width on it . Also post code to show when you are adding the progress bar to the view .

Comment: Adding `android:gravity` to the `ProgressBar` didn't fix it. And the `ProgressBar` is added programatically in the adapter which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` (please see the link I posted in the question. It's exactly the same except for the `ConstraintLayout` in the `activity_main.xml`).